# Using the front camera for video calls on Nokia Lumia 620 using 3G network

Tags: 8.0, lumia, 3g

How do I use the front camera on my Nokia Lumia 620 for video calls using 3G network? I am able to use the front camera for Skype calls etc. but not for 3G based video calls.

Others also seem to have similar [issues](http://qstacks.com/?qa=692/does-video-calling-is-supported-for-nokia-lumia-620).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Windows Phone 8 does not support network video calling through 3G- for now anyway. Your best bet is to use a third party application.

Comment: Can you recommend one?

Comment: Tango (http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/tango-video-calls/fe30c379-d111-427d-894f-dc3bfa0ec371) seems to be a good one and obviously you already use Skype